# Is there a variable list of all *valid* databases & schemas combinations in dbt jinja?

Tags: jinja2, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

Doing a variation on [this example](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/setting-up-snowflake-the-exact-grant-statements-we-run/439) for a macro (`grant_select_on_schemas.sql`) to set grants on a snowflake instance after dbt runs. My issue is that I've inherited a non-standard dbt build configuration which includes some statically defined *non-target* model locations.

Examples:

```
snowflake-instance
    |
    |> raw_db
        |> elt_schema_1
        |> elt_schema_2
        |> elt_schema_3
    |> utils_db
        |> calendar_schema_1
    |> staging_db
        |> elt_staging_1
        |> elt_staging_2
        |> elt_staging_3
    |> analytics_db
        |> core_models
        |> mart_1
        |> mart_2
```

`profiles.yml`

```
  target: prod
  outputs:
    prod:
      type: snowflake
      account: my-account.region-1
      role: my-role

      # User/password auth
      user: <user>
      password: <pass>

      database: raw_db
      warehouse: my-warehouse
      schema: PUBLIC
      threads: 2
      client_session_keep_alive: False
      query_tag: my-dbt-local
```

`dbt-project.yml`

```
models:
    my-pro:
        +materialized: table   
        utils:
            +database: UTILS
            +materialized: table
            calendar:
                +schema: calendar_schema_1
        staging:
            +database: staging_db
            +materialized: view
            elt_staging_1:
                +schema: elt_staging_1
            elt_staging_2:
                +schema: elt_staging_2
            elt_staging_3:
                +schema: elt_staging_3
```

`grant_select_on_schemas.sql`

```
-- macros/grants/grant_select_on_schemas.sql

{% macro grant_select_on_schemas(schemas, role) %}
  {% for schema in schemas %}
    {% for role in roles %}
      grant usage on schema {{ schema }} to role {{ role }};
      grant select on all tables in schema {{ schema }} to role {{ role }};
      grant select on all views in schema {{ schema }} to role {{ role }};
      grant select on future tables in schema {{ schema }} to role {{ role }};
      grant select on future views in schema {{ schema }} to role {{ role }};
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Currently, I'm running into the issue with this macro that the macro is attempting to run on against all schemas on my profile's `{{ target.database }}` (which is currently set to `staging_db`) and as a consequence is erroring when attempting things like:

```
> Database Error
>   002003 (02000): SQL compilation error:
>   Schema 'staging_db.core_models' does not exist or not authorized.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I joined stackoverflow just to answer your question because I had the same one 6-8+ months ago (I even double checked that this wasn't me asking the question because that would be embarrassing).

Checkout the `database_schemas` variable that lives in the depths of the dbt documentation:

https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/on-run-end-context#database_schemas

You should be able to add it in as such:

```
{% macro grant_select_on_schemas(database_schemas, role) %}
  {% for (database,schema) in database_schemas %}
    {% for role in roles %}
      grant usage on schema {{ database }}.{{ schema }} to role {{ role }};
      grant select on all tables in schema {{ database }}.{{ schema }} to role {{ role }};
      grant select on all views in schema {{ database }}.{{ schema }} to role {{ role }};
      grant select on future tables in schema {{ database }}.{{ schema }} to role {{ role }};
      grant select on future views in schema {{ database }}.{{ schema }} to role {{ role }};
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: Noting this explicitly since it frustrated me for a bit - the `database_schemas` variable is only populated after a `dbt run`. If you attempt to use this as a `dbt run-operation grant_select` the variable will be blank...